# SML Option Monad (bind operator not working)

Tags: operators, bind, monads, sml

I want to implement Option Monad in SML, so I can use them the same way they can be used in haskell. What I did, does not work.

```
infix 1 >>=
signature MONAD =
sig
    type 'a m 
    val return : 'a -> 'a m 
    val >>= : 'a m * ('a -> 'b m) -> 'b m 
end;

structure OptionM : MONAD =
struct
    type 'a m = 'a option
    val return = SOME
    fun x >>= k = Option.mapPartial k x
end;

val x = OptionM.return 3;
x (OptionM.>>=) (fn y => NONE);
```

Result:

```
stdIn:141.1-141.31 Error: operator is not a function [tycon mismatch] 
operator: int OptionM.m
in expression:
x OptionM.>>=
```

What can I do to make the last line work?

Comment: Here is one [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14129095/2747511) - just `open OptionM`.

Comment: Or `val op >>= = OptionM.>>=`.

Answer (score 7):

Unlike in Haskell, qualified infix operators (such as `A.+` or `Option.>>=`) are not infix in SML. You need to use them unqualified, e.g. by either opening the module or by rebinding it locally.

Btw, you probably want to define `>>=` as right-associative, i.e., use `infixr`.

Also, SML has stricter precedence rules than Haskell. That will make it somewhat more tedious to chain several uses of `>>=` with lambdas, because you have to parenthesise each `fn` on the right:

```
foo >>= (fn x => bar >>= (fn y => baz >>= (fn z => boo)))
```

Comment: A quote from [The Definition of Standard ML (Revised)](http://sml-family.org/sml97-defn.pdf), §2.6: "(Note that qualified identifiers never have infix status.)"

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the second and third paragraphs in this answer, because it seems to me that the >>= operator should be left-associative (as it is in Haskell), and furthermore it does seem to work in SML with anonymous functions without the need for the stacked parentheses. But I know Andreas is an SML expert so maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @xyz, you are right, I don't know what I was thinking regarding associativity! Thanks for the correction. But you definitely need the parens: `x <op> fn y => e` is never legal in SML, because according to its full grammar (Appendix B of the SML Definition), infix operators only allow further applications or atomic expressions as operands. If you encountered an implementation that accepts it, I'd be curious to know.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg Thank you. Regarding the parens, I just meant that with the left-associativeness meaning we can write `x >>= (fn y => e) >>= (fn z => e)`, then SML isn't really causing any ugliness/tedium. i.e. there's no "fingernail clippings" at the end, as people have uncharitably called them in Lisp.